# debugging(eclipse) using for loop cannot get an expected answer

Tags: java, android, debugging, logic

I am beginner in java and trying to teach myself before going to college.So here is my simple program,

```
public class Lesson_16_1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter;

    for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2);
    System.out.println("the counter is at "  + counter);
    }
}
```

The expected variables should be **5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19**.

Instead what i get the output is " **the counter is at 21**"

I do not understand why the value come **21** although  i clearly state the condition <=20.Please reply me as soon as possible.Thanks million.

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolon which "stops" for-cycle to do anything else

So change this

```
 for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2);
```

to this

```
 for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2)
```

---

Also good advice - ALWAYS use braces, it does not hurt and the code is more readable :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter;

    for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2){
        System.out.println("the counter is at "  + counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `for loop` doesn't have a body (nothing to execute while iterating)

```
for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2); // it is ending here
```

You need to change your code to following to get what you are expecting

```
 for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2){
    System.out.println("the counter is at "  + counter);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used a semicolon at the end of `for` statement , here :

```
for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2);
```

the syntax to write the for loop is as follows ,

```
for(initialization ; condition ; step ){

//repeatable task here 
}
```

here `step` can be like `incrementing` the loop variable (which in your case is `counter`) or `decrementing`.
if your repeatable task is a single statement (which is your case) then you can write for loop without curly braces , as follows ,

```
for(counter = 5; counter <= 20; counter=counter+2)
    System.out.println("the counter is at "  + counter);
```

but as i mentioned it is only for single statement .